# tips While adding a data from more than 1 computer to a database that is locate on central server

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My application is in VS 2008 (vb.net Windows form)
I want tips for this:
What types of care I take for it?
What types of problems can be generally happen?

Answer (score 1):

The question is extremely vague and broad as written, and is likely to be closed, however here's some things that you might want to consider to help with your thinking

1. Should the application have only [one instance](http://joelbennett.wordpress.com/2007/04/14/using-a-mutex-to-prevent-multiple-copies-of-an-application-from-runningc/) open or are multiple instances okay.
2. What kind of start up time should it have.
3. Is it okay if my application eats up all the machines resources like a Kiosk applcation or does the software need to be a good citizen.
4. What are the permissions that my application needs to get its work done.
5. What are the activities that might be long running that we need to take care that the application does freeze up.
6. Should it be a [WPF or Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703681/winforms-vs-wpf) application

You might want to review this guidance [Improving .NET Application Performance and Scalability](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=8A2E454D-F30E-4E72-B531-75384A0F1C47&displaylang=en).